# Session Count on JBoss AS 7.1

Tags: java, session, web-applications, servlets, jboss7.x

How can I see the http-session count for my JBoss AS 7.1 instance.

I can't find anything on the JBoss Application Server 7.1 Management Console.

Last time I used JBoss AS was version 4.3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about a specific application then you can use 'HttpSessionListener' or using 'HttpSessionBindingListener' http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html

Comment: I was hoping for a way other than using a Listener. But cool idee.

Answer (score 0):

This would look at the sessions from inside the servlet container.
On the other hand the container should be able to count them as well. Old JBosses were able to disclose the information on a JMX bean

```
jboss.web:host=localhost,path=/<context-name>,type=Manager
```

with an attribute named 'activeSessions'.

On recent JBosses, the value is available in a different location, which is best explained here:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/219739?_sscc=t